# how to open the linux magazine from software center for FREE?

Tags: 14.04

how to download it when it shows under books and magazines in the software center as i click the install button doesn't appear, on one hand it shows buy but on the other hand they say it is free.
it doesn't even has a price tag.
how do i read the ubuntu linux magazine?

Answer (score 2):

All the `linux` branded magazines in the software center COST MONEY, these are real magazines people published and you must pay for them no where does it say the linux magazines are free, you can buy them right off the main page, see the buy button in the screenshot

[image]

You can read `full circle magazine` for free though, it is a `free independent magazine for the Ubuntu community` says the description

[image]